# How to decrypt already encrypted answer

Tags: javascript

I don't know if this is the place to ask or if even I could get some pointers in the correct way. I've managed to get my code to encrypt the text but I want to reverse it when I press a button, to paste the orginal value into a button when you hit decrypt. So say you type "Hello" with 5 shifts it encrypts tomjqqt. I want it so when I press decrypt it puts "hello" into a text field. Sorry if this isn't allowed to be asked but I really have tried for hours and hours.

JS;

```
function encryption() {    
        var str = document.getElementById("encryptedValue").value;
        var output = ""
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++) {
            var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
            if ((code >= 20) && (code <= 30))
                c = String.fromCharCode(((code - 65 + amount)) + 65);
    }
}
function decryption()
            var str = document.getElementById("deCrypted").value;
            var output = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++) {
                var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
                if ((code >= 20) && (code <= 30))
                    c = String.fromCharCode(((code - 65 + amount));
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for (it's more of a hack but totally eliminates the decrypt function), but why not copy the encrypted value to a hidden text field, then when clicking to decrypt, simply read the hidden field?

JS:

```
function encryption() {
    switch (document.getElementById("methods").value) {
        case "Encrypt":
            var str = document.getElementById("text_encode").value;
            // store the original string in a hidden field
            document.getElementById("text_HiddenField").value = str;

            var amount = Number(prompt("Number of shift"));
            var output = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                var c = str[i];
                var code = str.charCodeAt(i);

                if ((code >= 65) && (code <= 90))
                    c = String.fromCharCode(((code - 65 + amount) % 26) + 65);
                else if ((code >= 97) && (code <= 122))
                    c = String.fromCharCode(((code - 97 + amount) % 26) + 97);

                output += c;
            }
            document.getElementById("text_decoded").value = output;
            break;
    }
}

function decryption() {
    switch (document.getElementById("methods1").value) {
        case "Decrypt":
            str = document.getElementById("text_HiddenField").value;
            document.getElementById("text_decoded").value = str;
            break;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="methods">Select your methods : </label>
<br>
<br>
<select name="methods" id="methods">

    <option value="Encrypt">Encrypt</option>


</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Encrypt" onClick=encryption()>


<br>
<br>
<textarea name="text" id="text_decoded" style="width: 10%;height: 40px"></textarea>

<textarea name="text" id="text_encode"> Enter message here: That you wish to decrypt</textarea>
<textarea name="text" id="text_HiddenField"></textarea> <!--Hide This-->
<br>
<br>

<label for="methods1">Select your methods : </label>
<br>
<br>
<select name="methods" id="methods1">

    <option value="Decrypt">Decrypt</option>


</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Decrypt" onClick=decryption()>
```

Comment: That would be great, I tried doing that too but didn't really know where to start again. Could you possibly give some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running your encryption function again, but this time make `amount` negative and pass in the encrypted text. This should reverse the encryption.

Comment: Okay, Ill give it a try. I've got the shift part working but I just need to someone display the given output from the encoded text into the field to be able to decrypt the text

Comment: Your problem is that the "text_decoded1" field specified in your JS doesn't match what you have available in the HTML